# Estamos recebendo sugestões de tags nas perguntas?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-aceito, tags

Usando o SO me deparei com:

[image: tags recomendadas]

Não me lembro de ter visto isto aqui no SOpt (fiz um teste com o meu post no SO e aqui). Isto está funcionando? Se não, podemos ter?

Acredito ser de valia principalmente para os novatos.